# Debugging Android 5.0 over USB

Tags: android, debugging

When battery is fully charged, the notification "Battery Fully charged. Unplug charger" stays on. It is covering some buttons on the UI and I have to disconnect the USB cable to get rid of it.

Anybody knows how to get rid of that notification while debugging?

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of what you mean? I don't think I've ever seen a 'fully charged' notification that covers the UI..

Comment: HA! When I was swiping my palm to take a screen shot, the view moved away! I guess I had to swipe it to the side to get rid of it. I will post a picture when it is up again so other people can see.    (EDIT) I cannot take screen shot with palm swiping as it swipes that view away! Thank you for suggesting a screen shot.